# Why do eBGP neighbors need to be physically connected to each other

Tags: routing, bgp

In *Halabi - Chapter 6* it states that, "*External BGP neighbors have a restriction in that they must be physically connected, adjacent to one another.*" 
There are tuning knobs that lets us override this restriction.

But why is it required for them to be directly connected in normal scenarios? What is the rationale behind this requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you don't have any routes from the other AS in order for eBGP to be able to find a different interface. You will be given the directly connected interface, but the router would need to be manually configured to find a different interface in the router of the other AS.

Your router and the router in the other AS must share a directly connected network. That network will automatically be in the routing tables of each of those two routers. Each of the routers has no other routes into the opposite AS. If you want to use loopbacks for eBGP, you would need to manually create static routes in each of the routers which point to the next hop. The routers already know how to find the next hop, so it is much easier to just use that for the neighbor relationship.

Comment: ++ great answer, but perhaps mention "multihop"?

Comment: How that is done varies by vendor. He mentions tuning knobs, so he knows there are ways to do this, but I didn't want to get too vendor-specific in my answer.

Comment: ok, understood.

Answer (score 0):

By default, eBGP uses 1 as a Time-To-Live(TTL) value, therefore, if peers are not attached directly, then TTL will be decremented to 0 and the packet will be discarded.

However, if the eBGP neighbor is multihop far, then the alternative is to increase the TTL value by “**neighbor x.x.x.x ebgp-multihop 2**”

Comment: Those are the knobs mentioned by the OP, but the router will still need a route to know how to get to the non-directly attached interface. Just using multihop with an address that the router does not know how to reach will not work.